# When creating a json array, if the text has a special Character it shows nothing

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've been trying to create a json response but one of the results is this "Wisin - Esc�pate Conmigo (Official Video) ft. Ozuna"

This is what i have right now

$recentTreningVideos = GetTrendingVideos($con);
    //$newlyAddedVideos = GetNewlyAddedVideos($con);

```
//ob_start();


$array[] = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");   

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recentTreningVideos))
{


    $TrendImageURL = $row['youtubethumbnail'];
    $TrendSongName = $row['musicvideotitle'];
    $TrendCleanSongname = $row['songname'];

    $array[] = array(
                    "youtubethumbnail" => $row['youtubethumbnail'], 
                    "key2" => "xcvxcv"
                    );
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

it does not show anything at all not even error how can I use that character, or make it so it at least shows the json

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean by "show"?  When that data is rendered in a web browser?  "Something else"?

Comment: What? Where? How? Show us some code, man.

Comment: FYI, the "character" in question seems to be the two-byte sequence "0xBF 0xBD".  I'm curious how it looks in your "source" (for example, do a "select" of that row in MySql).

Comment: Updated question with a bit more details

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with encoding. Do you use header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
In your php? if not try. Where the data coming? it's can be also mysql encoding.

Comment: I'm not sure who marked you down.  This isn't an "answer" - but your conclusions are good, as are your questions.

Comment: Yes sorry I give answer question at the same time 